# Connecting to a GCloud Spanner Emulator instance from Intellij's Database Navigator Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

I'm running [`gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator`](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator) in a Docker container on my dev machine. I would like to connect to the database from the [Intellij Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) so that I can see what data was written to my tables.

In Database Navigator, I have created a new Generic connection and configured it to make use of the [google-cloud-spanner-jdbc](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner-jdbc) driver (version 1.17.3, obtained from [maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-spanner-jdbc/1.17.3/jar)), using the connection string

```
jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost:9010/projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/databases/main;usePlainText=true
```

as [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-oss-jdbc#connecting_to_the_emulator), but with the correct project, instance, and database name subbed in. Crucially, I have included the `usePlainText=true` parameter [as documented in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63879318/when-connecting-to-google-cloud-spanner-emulator-with-jdbc-credentials-that-sho).

When I test the connection, I get an error message that says

> Cannot connect to "Spanner Localstack". INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid properties found in connection URI: v$session.program, ApplicationName

Has anybody successfully connected Intellij's Database Navigator to the cloud-spanner-emulator using the google-cloud-spanner-jdbc driver?

Answer (score 2):

Your setup and JDBC URL all seem to be ok. The problem is caused by the following combination that is out of your control:

1. Database Navigator automatically add this to the connection properties: https://bitbucket.org/dancioca/dbn/src/d67a09f92b4b9f27e0d1feb91dada9bf0fe802eb/src/com/dci/intellij/dbn/connection/Connector.java?at=master#lines-92
2. The Cloud Spanner JDBC Driver checks that it only receives known properties: https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/907ae1ff2f5c0b60510c435f5ba270bd92827104/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/connection/ConnectionOptions.java#L602

As the Cloud Spanner JDBC driver does not know all the properties that Database Navigator is adding, it will refuse the connection. I'll have a look and see if we can get that fixed in the JDBC driver.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see if I can raise an issue with the Database Navigator maintainer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Spanner JDBC driver now supports a boolean connection property `lenient` to ignore unknown properties. Setting `lenient=true` will force the Spanner JDBC driver to ignore unknown properties in the connection URL.

Reference - https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner-jdbc/blob/main/README.md#advanced-properties